# How can I output the result of my .py script in the CLI when running my Ansible playbook?

Tags: python, docker-compose, ansible

As the title states I am currently struggling to output the result of my `.py` script. I have looked around and tried to implement many of the examples I've seen on StackOverflow/Reddit, e.g.:

- Using `register` & `debug` parameters
- Using above parameters with `stdout`
- Using above parameters with `stdout_lines`

Currently, when I run `docker-compose up` I have *no* issues; desired output is seen in the CLI (shows disk usage).

However, when I run `docker-compose up` using an `ansible-playbook` I see an output that details various server related info and is **NOT** what I want to see when the playbook is run. I only want to see the result of the disk clean-up script.

See Python scripts and Ansible playbook code below:

**`my_modules.py`**

```python
import time, os, shutil

path = os.getcwd()

total, used, free = shutil.disk_usage(path)

total_2_dp = round(total / 2^^30, 2)
used_2_dp = round(used / 2^^30, 2)
free_2_dp = round(free / 2^^30, 2)

def dfcleanup():
    
timestamp = os.path.getmtime(path)

    days = 40

    s_in_days = time.time() - (days * 24 * 60 * 60) 

    for file in os.listdir(path):
        filename = os.fsdecode(file)

        if timestamp >= s_in_days:
            os.remove(filename)

            break
```

**`df_cleanup.py`** (this script prints disk usage)

```yaml
from clean_up_msg import clean_up_message

from my_modules import *

threshold = 80

if (used / total)*100 >= threshold:

    dfcleanup(), clean_up_message()
    print("Clean up complete (:")
    print(f"Disk Usage:\nTotal: {total_2_dp} GiB, Used: {used_2_dp} GiB, Free: {free_2_dp} GiB")

else: 
    
    print(f"Disk Usage:\nTotal: {total_2_dp} GiB, Used: {used_2_dp} GiB, Free: {free_2_dp} GiB")
```

**`docker-compose up`** to run `.py` script and [running docker-compose up (output I want)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TKt6r.png)

Finally the Ansible playbook to run `docker-compose up`

```yaml
---
 - hosts: all
   become: true

   tasks:

    - name: copy file with owner & permissions
      ansible.builtin.copy: 
         src: /home/user/project-directory/docker-compose.yml       
         dest: /home/user/docker-compose.yml

    - name: run docker-compose up
        community.docker.docker_compose:
          project_src: /home/user/
          files:
          - "docker-compose.yml"
      state: present
      register: df_output

    - debug:
         msg: "{{ df_output }}"
```

and The Ansible playbook output [running `ansible-playbook` (output I get)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yNswz.png)

Comment: What you are seeing when launching manually is the output of your docker container(s) as you did not launch in the background (using `-d`). The ansible module does not attach to your container(s) stdout and returns as soon as the container(s) is/are launched (which is quite fortunate since it would never end until the container is stopped by an other process when launching e.g. a web server or a java application). The only thing you get in the registered var is the result of the task, not of  what is running inside your container(s). You will have to get the container(s) logs for that.

Comment: Thanks Zeitounator. I came to the same conclusion. Solved with the following:

`ansible.builtin.shell: docker logs df-clean-up`

`register: python_cleanup_output`

`- debug:
    msg: "{{ python_cleanup_output.stdout_lines }}"`

Had to also configure docker-compose up task to always recreate as it was storing logs from previous runs